# WCF: Server rejects credentials when calling from WindowsService

Tags: wcf, windows-services, credentials, impersonation

I have a WCF service interacting with some Form applications using NetTcpBinding in order to use Callbacks. It's working just fine.

Now I'd like to use that same WCF service from a WindowsService running under LocalService account. The aim of this is to input some data that will be shown in the Forms. I only need to use one of the functions, lets call it "`PushInfo(data as MyData)`"

As far as I know I cannot do that using LocalService account, so I set up this in order to use some AD credentials:

```
myclientWCF = New ServiceReference.GatewayClient(context)
myclientWCF.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "John"
myclientWCF.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "EvilCorpDomain"
myclientWCF.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "spaceballs"
myclientWCF.PushInfo(myData)
```

If I do this, the call gets rejected by the server due to invalid credentials.

What am I missing?

I have read that I should use:

```
myclientWCF.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = New NetworkCredential("John", "spaceballs", "EvilCorpDomain")
```

but I get the same result, in fact I cannot see how that is different from my approach.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `myclientWCF.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;`

Comment: Thank you. I tried but unfortunately it didn't work. Guess I'm missing something else

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like I was missing this statement:

```
myclientWCF.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

although I'm not sure HOW/WHY it works. I'll look into that.

I've been working around this the whole day and I make it work 10 minutes after I post the question. Is it a good practice to leave here both question and answer or should I delete the post?

Comment: Leave it, it might help someone else. But an explanation as to why that worked would be nice too :)